# Why do i need to subtract 7 from the while condition in the end for my code to work correctly

Tags: c++

I am new to coding and i am trying to print fabonacci sequence and i cannot understand why i am unable to get the output correct without subtracting 7 from my while loop condition . And can anyone tell me how to fix this problem.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    double y;
    double z;
    int x;

    cout <<"Enter the number you want to find the sequence of :";
    cin>>x;

    int zero = 1;

    cout<<"Sequence equal to or less than "<<x<<" is :"<<"0";

    do {
        z = (pow(1.618,zero)-pow(-0.618,zero))/2.236;
        zero++;
        y=ceil(z);
        cout<<","<<y;
    } while(y<=x-7);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You "need" to subtract 7 because you want the last value printed to be smaller than `x`, but you check the condition after printing. Putting the `-7` makes the last value printed smaller than `x` sometimes, but not always. Try `x = 123` to get output `0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144` or `x = 3` to get `0,1` while it should be `0,1,1,2,3`.

To fix your code **first** check the condition and only then print it:

```
do {
    z = (pow(1.618,zero)-pow(-0.618,zero))/2.236;
    zero++;
    y=ceil(z);
    if (y <= x) {
        cout<<","<<y;
    } else {
        break;
    }
} while(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is there's too much happening in this loop:

```
int zero = 1;
do {
    z = (pow(1.618,zero)-pow(-0.618,zero))/2.236;
    zero++;
    y=ceil(z);
    cout<<","<<y;
} while(y<=x-7);
```

You are combining the iteration of `zero`, with the computation of `y`, with the check against `x`. Spelling out every step is error-prone, and if the loop is more than a few lines it becomes hard to tell what's going on. If your loop is not doing what you want, a good approach is to abstract out the details of the loop by wrapping that in a function.

For example, simply by refactoring the computation of `y`, like this:

```
auto fib = [](int zero) {
    return ceil((std::pow(1.618,zero) - std::pow(-0.618,zero)) / 2.236);
};
```

You can use a much more natural loop construct for the problem:

```
for(int zero = 1; (y = fib(zero)) <= x; ++zero)
        std::cout<<","<<y;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hzd71E).

This is still more complexity than necessary. From c++20, you could declare all the fibonacci numbers:

```
auto fib_nums = std::views::iota(1) | std::views::transform(fib);
```

This has the nice advantage that it can be used for different purposes, and keeps generating fibonacci numbers forever.

Now your loop can just do the needed comparison:

```
for(int y : fib_nums | std::views::take_while([x](int y) { return y <= x; }))
    std::cout << "," << y;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qhdPcs).

Comment: Thank you for helping me out sir .